# PHP Array parent/child display/inherit

Tags: php, arrays, inheritance

I have an piece of my array here:

```
   [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8005
        [parentid] => 8004
        [name] => a, b
        [level] => 1
        [prodtypename] => 1, 2, 3, 4
    )

[1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8006
        [parentid] => 8005
        [name] => c
        [level] => 2
        [prodtypename] => 
    )

[2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8007
        [parentid] => 8005
        [name] => d
        [level] => 2
        [prodtypename] => 
    )
```

In my form I display them like:

```
 <?php foreach ($this->myArray as $item): ?>
 <?php echo $item->prodtypename ?>
```

it displays me current category and its current type. I need to display parent "prodtypename" next to child type, so we can know, what is parents types for current child category. Im trying to make display look something like this:

```
 [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [id] => 8006
        [parentid] => 8005
        [name] => c
        [level] => 2
        [prodtypename] => 1,2,3,4
    )
```

Because parents "prodtypename" have 1.2.3.4, so the child inherits it. Thanks.

Comment: Are you getting your data from somewhere else, e.g. a database? It might be easier to achieve what you want at that point.

Comment: Yeah, data come from database.

Comment: can you do a `print_r` instead of a `var_dump` a `print_r` better to read :)

Comment: done, thx for hint, is do look better :)

Comment: @Raim You might be better asking a different question with your data structure to see if you can get that info into the array in the first place but I have posted an answer that should work on this array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the array you have already something like this might work assuming that you can rely on parents always appearing in the array before their children:

```
$prodTypeNames = array();
foreach ($this->myArray as $item) {
    $prodTypeName = $item->prodtypename;
    if( is_null( $item->prodtypename ) && isset( $prodTypeNames[$item->parentid] ) ) {
        $prodTypeName = $prodTypeNames[$item->parentid];
    }
    $prodTypeNames[$item->id] = $prodTypeName;
    echo $prodTypeName;
}
```

But you're probably better off getting the data in a better format to begin with.

Comment: Great, thanks you a lot. It`s dont work for 100% correct, but it gets me out of where i was stuck. Thanks you very much :)